# Is there a linear lower bound for averaging over logarithmic domain?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, logarithms, average, upper-lower-bounds

Let $\mathbf{x} \in R^{n}$ be a strictly positive vector with $x_1,x_2, \cdots, x_n$ being its elements. I have following function $f(\mathbf{x})$, which is the averaging of $\mathbf{x}$ in logarithmic domain,

\begin{equation}
f(\mathbf{x}) = \exp \left( \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \ln(x_i)}{n}\right)
\end{equation}

I wonder, if there exists any tight linear lower bound $g(\mathbf{x})$,  for $f(\mathbf{x})$  (i.e., $g(\mathbf{x})\leq f(\mathbf{x})~~ \forall \mathbf{x}>0$) ?

Comment: Doesn't $f(\mathbf{x})$ simplify to $f(\mathbf{x})=\left(\,\prod_{i=1}^nx_i\,\right)^{1/n}?$ If so, that might help you out some.

Comment: I should think $g(\mathbf{x})=\min\{x_i\}$ would work, wouldn't it? Unless that's not linear, in the sense you mean it.